# Android - non UI Thread rendering my UI unresponsive

Tags: java, android, multithreading, inputstream, outputstream

When I call this thread in my activity it makes the UI unresponsive and so I am unable to do anything once it has started. I would assume it has to do with the I/O streams but I am not sure how to resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated but I am new to Android and threading so I may have some followup questions.

Here is my thread:

```
 mHandler = new Handler();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run () {
                    int counter = 0;
                    while (true) {
                        counter++;
                        try {
                            output = "";
                            if (mInStream != null) {
                                mInStream.read(buffer);
                                for (byte b : buffer) {
                                    char c = (char) b;
                                    if (c >= ' ' && c < 'z') {
                                        //System.out.print(c);
                                        output += c;
                                    }
                                }
                                //System.out.println();
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction("com.curie.WEIGHT_RECEIVED");
                                intent.putExtra("Output",output);

                                if (counter % 10 == 0) {
                                    System.out.println(counter);
                                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(InputActivity.getContext()).sendBroadcastSync(intent);
                                }
                            }
                            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            //an exception here marks connection loss
                            //send message to UI Activity
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

EDIT: The answer did fix my problem I now am receiving this error though. 
This error occurs when I call `inputwindow.setText(weight)` which sets the text in a TextView to the value that was broadcast from the thread.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2358
        Process: com.example.curie.fairbanks_03, PID: 15718
        android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1364)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5433)
        at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13997)
        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13961)
        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13945)
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8403)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5011)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4836)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4811)
        at com.example.curie.fairbanks_03.InputActivity$2.onReceive(InputActivity.java:67)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:311)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcastSync(LocalBroadcastManager.java:289)
        at com.example.curie.fairbanks_03.BluetoothConnection$2.run(BluetoothConnection.java:176)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Have you verified that `run` actually happens on a separate thread (e.g. using `adb logcat -v threadtime`)?  `new Handler();` will give you a `Handler` associated with the `Looper` _for the current thread_.

Comment: When I run the thread in my activity it prints the broadcast to the console so i can see that it is running and working, but then i cant do anything on the screen after that.

Comment: Well, I wasn't asking if you've verified if the `Runnable` ever runs. I was asking if you've verified _which thread_ it ends up running on.

Comment: I am not sure how to determine that.

Comment: One way would to be by adding a log print and then use the `adb` command I mentioned in my first comment to see which thread the log came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is making your UI unresponsive because it is running *in the UI thread*! You start a new thread to run the task, but then in that thread you call `mHandler.post` which just goes back to the thread in which `mHandler` was created, which is the UI thread. There is no reason to do that. Just perform the operation in the thread you created without calling the handler.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            counter++;
            try {
                output = "";
                if (mInStream != null) {
                    mInStream.read(buffer);
                    for (byte b : buffer) {
                        char c = (char) b;
                        if (c >= ' ' && c < 'z') {
                            //System.out.print(c);
                            output += c;
                        }
                    }
                    //System.out.println();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("com.curie.WEIGHT_RECEIVED");
                    intent.putExtra("Output",output);

                    if (counter % 10 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(counter);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(InputActivity.getContext()).sendBroadcastSync(intent);
                    }
                }
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //an exception here marks connection loss
                //send message to UI Activity
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: i have received this error now: (it has been added to my post. )

Comment: however the code you provided did work and answer my question. Thank you!